# Presto Trino - Execute from SQL file

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Beginner. Using CLI/Presto/Trino. Not sure the right term. It looks to be command line and we are using Hive.

I can run select, create tables. I'm trying to run multiple queries at once. I created SQL file and uploaded to Hive folder structure. I think I can execute all of them at once instead of going one by one.

How do I initiate the process of running SQL query from file?

--execute  file user/hivefile.sql > result getting nowhere

Answer (score 0):

By using the below command you can run queries

```
presto --server <server-name>:<port> --catalog <catalog-name> --schema <schema-name> --file <path-to-file>
```